# Get the sum of combinations of values in 3 columns of a 5 column dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4), c=c(3,5), d=c(6,5), e=c(9,2))
```

I want to write a function that gives me all the possible combinations of the 3 of the column values. The desired output would be

```
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10
1  7   10  13  10  3   16  12  15  18  18
2  11  11  8   12  9   9   14  11  11  12
```

**I would like to write a loop that would go through the different combinations of the `n` number of the columns, which in this question `n=3`**

Comment: Your output doesn't match the description of what you want. How are the values given combinations of the df columns if they are completely different values? I'm thinking there's a hidden step, some operation you'd like to do?

Comment: I rolled your question back since the edit was very different from the original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use `combn`on the sequence of the number of columns of your data frame (i.e. `1:5` or `seq(5)`) and then use it as index to subset the data frame. Then `rowSums()` will add the values, i.e.

```
combn(seq_along(df), 3, FUN = function(i) rowSums(df[i]))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    7   10   13   10   13   16   12   15   18    18
[2,]   11   11    8   12    9    9   14   11   11    12
```

Another way of using `combn` (credits to @nicola):

```
combn(df,3,rowSums)
```

If you have different combinations for each row, then 1 way is to loop over the individual rows, i.e.

```
sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) max(combn(df[i, 1:5], df$Lanes[i], sum)))
#[1] 18 16
```

Comment: I was just wondering why I get an error if I use a variable in the data frame instead of 3 in `max(combn(df[,1:5], Lanes, FUN = function(i) rowSums(df[i])))` where `df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4), c=c(3,5), d=c(6,5), e=c(9,2), Lanes=c(3,4))` @Sotos and @nicola I have edited the original question to include this

Comment: @MaralDorri Your edit completely changes the question. Should this happen in the future please just open a new question. I did however answered your new requirements.

Comment: @Sotos I put a strikeout on your last edit to reflect the rollback I made in the question. As edited, the question was confusing and missed details (for instance the `n=3` bit).

Comment: @nicola I wished you would have told me first. That is a major edit to make. Especially since it's a new user and I commented that they should have opened a new question and did it as a favor. The main reason I did is because there are no other answers so it's not unfair to anyone.

Comment: @Sotos Yes, sorry, I saw the edit only a few hours ago. Apparently, OP opened another question. I made the edit to better match question's content, which I rolled back since the original was interesting and had your good answer which made little sense with the edit. As I see now, your edit is compatible with the question and can stay in my opinion.